# Linting Terraform: How can I disable or ignore tflint rules?

Tags: terraform, tflint

I have a terraform file that creates a table in dynamodb.  When tflint runs in github it gives this error:

```
2023-08-16 15:28:25 [ERROR]   Found errors in [terrascan] linter!
2023-08-16 15:28:25 [ERROR]   Error code: 3. Command output:
Violation Details -
    Description    :    Ensure DynamoDb is encrypted at rest
```

I want to disable this check.  Here is what I've tried and nothing works:

```
# tflint-ignore: server_side_encryption
# tflint-disable: server_side_encryption
# tflint-ignore: all
```

I need a way to disable tflint checks within the .tf file that works.

The [tflint docs](https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint/blob/v0.47.0/docs/user-guide/annotations.md) are worthless, unfortunately.